# Laravel Nova: How to hide fields only when updating the resource

Tags: laravel-nova, laravel-authorization

I know I can hide some fields with `canSee` method:

```
Text::make('Something')
    ->canSee(function ($request) {
        return $request->user()->can('some ability');
    }),
```

And from the [documentation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/authorization.html#fields), there is a `canSeeWhen` method where you can hide the field based on the abilities the user has:

```
canSeeWhen('viewProfile', $this);
```

But these methods work for every situation, for example if I define the `canSee` method on a field, the field is not seeable on index, detail, creating, and updating pages.

I want to hide some fields specifically when the user is **editing** the resource.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got it. You can use `hideWhenUpdating` method.

```
Text::make('Something')->hideWhenUpdating();
```

Other methods are:

```
hideFromIndex
hideFromDetail
hideWhenCreating
hideWhenUpdating
onlyOnIndex
onlyOnDetail
onlyOnForms
exceptOnForms
```